# Rigging problem. When i try to bend the knee, it doesn't bend, it splits in two pieces

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation, rigify, rigidbody

I have a problem trying to rig a leg. It works perfectly with the arms and any other thing i tried the Armature tool on.

I have used a cylinder for the leg and scaled it in the Y direction for the hieght.
Then i rigged it (armature) but when i try to bend the knee, it doesn't bend. Then i saw a blog that said i need to add some edgeloop along the height of the cylinder. Done that now it turns into two pieces. One bent one not. See the picture.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.